# Sequelize onDelete cascade not setting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, has-many, cascade

I have an issue with sequelize associations.
I am tryign to set `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` to my `hasMany` association which looks like this

```
Model.hasMany(models.Income, {
    foreignKey: 'companyId',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```

But unfortunately It doesn't set it in MySQL, instead I got SET NULL on my server.
What is wrong with my association?

Comment: Is that a supported feature on MySQL? I'm pretty sure Postgres has this, but I can't speak to the other drivers.

Comment: Yes, this is supported by MySQL too. Also I checked generated sql code and that has code `ON DELETE SET NULL`, instead of `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: I guess my configuration is wrong, but there is really little about that in docs,  so I can't find right way of this

Comment: The Sequelize core team is pretty responsive if you can find a way of poking them, so that's worth a shot. If you can create a reproducible bug, post an issue and they'll probably fix it quickly. I've had them jump on things really quickly in the past over issues like this.

Comment: Yes, I created issue on github, hopefully they will contact me